# pgAdmin4: What username do I select?

Tags: macos, homebrew, pgadmin-4

So I have installed PostgreSQL on my new macOS via `Homebrew`, but instead of doing all the work via CLI like I prefer, I want to use pgAdmin4 to make it easier for demonstration purposes for a less technical crowd.

For creating a server in pgAdmin4 where I am trying to make a connection, do I use the default PostgreSQL username that comes with doing an install with Homebrew or do I use the same username for accessing my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the Homebrew system has you log in to the PostgreSQL server using `postgres` username seems to be of no relevance, you will have to use the **Username** in **pgAdmin4** of whatever results you get from doing a `whoami` on your terminal.